# Set the width of a column in a datagrid?

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

How do I set the width of a column in a `DataGrid` (not a `DataGridView`)?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's something like this:

```
dg.TableStyles(0).GridColumnStyles(0).Width = 120
```

Answer (score 0):

Private Sub dgColumnWidths()
'Var = 0 for first column
Dim Var As Integer
DataGrid1.Columns(Var).Width = 1000
End Sub

Comment: You are resurrecting a question that has been dead for over 6 years with an  answer that doesn't adds any value here. You should either reformat it so it is actually readable or remove it all together. Also, this question has not formally been answered but from the comment provided on the previous answer it is clear that the OP was able to solve his problem with it.